# I am confused about <T> vs <? extends T>. When to use the bounded wildcard?

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

If I have a basic class Pair with a generic constructor:

```
private T first;
private S second;

public Pair(Pair<T, S> p) {
    this(p.first, p.second);
}
```

like so, then what is the difference between this and this?

```
private T first;
private S second;


public Pair(Pair<? extends T, ? extends S> p) {
    this(p.first, p.second);
}
```

I understand that the second example is an upper bounded wildcard meaning that the Type can be T or any subclass of T but if I do something like:

```
Pair<Animal, Animal> animalPair = new Pair<>(new Cat("Tiddles"), new Dog("Rover"));
```

or:

```
Pair<Number, Number> numberPair = new Pair<>(2.97, 7545498865L);
```

then these arguments are subclasses of T and S anyway so the compiler doesn't complain with or without the ? extends part.

When would you use ? extends T instead of just T? Sorry if this has been asked before, I just can't seem to find an example where you would need to use it.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super) is a good read.

Comment: You should also read the item in *Effective Java* called something like "Use bounded wildcards to increase the flexibility of your API".

Comment: Ok thanks for the links

Comment: `Pair<Double, Double> doublePair = new Pair<>(2.97,1.23); Pair<Number, Number> numberPair = new Pair<>(doublePair);`. Try that with the first and second ways.